# php preg_match returns only matched portion of string when I am certain that there is an unmatched portion too

Tags: php, preg-match

so I am trying to get all unmatched text, and I have code snippets that look like:
Row, Col    = (1, 1)
Row, Col    = (1, 2)
Row, Col    = (9999999, 9999999)
stored in an array called $foo my preg_match statement looks like:

```
foreach($foo as $fooPartition){
   if(preg_match("/.*\([0-9]+\, /", $fooPartition, $match)){
      $unecessaryFluff = $match[0];
      $infoINeed = $match[1];
   }
}
```

I keep on getting back $unecessaryFluff but I get a missing index when I try to access $match[1], and my debugger verifies that $match is in fact just a length 1 array containing the matched portion of the string, and $match[1] DNE.

Does anyone know What I am doing wrong that is making the preg_match not return the unmatched portion of the string per the php page specs? (using php 5.3.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify grouped expressions (using parentheses) if you want to isolate specific strings.

For example, say you just wanted the digits

```
/.*\(([0-9]+)\, /
```

Not sure why you're escaping the comma, is that a typo?